# How to put an array of object inside DynamodDB using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a JSON having an array of objects in the following format. How can i add it in dynamoDB using a lambda function(NodeJS). Assume my JSON is in an s3 bucket name "databucket" and the file name is data.json. I have used "userId" as the key while creating the DB table. Thanks in advance

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "first-name": "Mark",
      "last-name": "rob",
      "userId": "fvdvfd"
    },
    {
      "first-name": "Alan",
      "last-name": "thomas",
      "userId": "wee"
    },
    {
      "first-name": "Joan",
      "last-name": "Young",
       "userId": "wee"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you have to retrieve the data.json from S3 bucket and read it's content into a variable.
2. Secondly, you should create dynamodb parameter to provide to the dynamodb client PUT method. Since it is an array of objects you have to loop through the array and put each object or else you can use batchWrite method in dynamodb as follows,

   `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   var insertBatchRecords = function(callback) {
       var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
       var bulkInsertParams = {
               RequestItems: {
                   "Records": [
                              {
                                  PutRequest: { 
                                      Item: {
                                          "first-name": "Mark",
                                          "last-name": "rob",
                                          "userId": "fvdvfd"
                                          }
                              }},
                              {
                                  PutRequest: { 
                                      Item: {
                                          "first-name": "Alan",
                                          "last-name": "thomas",
                                          "userId": "wee"
                                          }
                              }}]
               }
           };
      dynamodb.batchWriteItem(bulkInsertParams, callback);
   }`